# IOS App rejected - your app is taking longer than expected

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Looking for some guidance on what to do. I have an app which has never been rejected with dozens of submissions to the app store. Last week however, I have submitted my binary 3 (currently trying for a 4th) times which keeps getting rejected with the following message.

> Hello,
>
> The review of your app is taking longer than expected. Once we have
>   completed our review, we will notify you via Resolution Center.
>
> If you would like to inquire about the status of this review, you may
>   file a request via the Apple Developer Contact Us page.
>
> Best regards,
>
> App Store Review

After the third time, I thought I'd leave it to see if anything happens but nothing does. I've sent 4 messages using the "Apple Developer Contact Us page" with no replies. Does anyone know why this is or could help in resolving this?

Comment: Your app isn't being rejected, it is just taking longer to review. If you are developer rejecting and submitting a new build each time you get this message then you yourself will be "resetting the clock" and making review take longer.  You have to wait until Apple contacts you with the result of the review.

Comment: @Luke Snowden, Hi did You get final review now from app review team?

Comment: @RipaSaha it took about a week but since then it has been back to normal

Comment: @LukeSnowden ok. I'll wait

Comment: @LukeSnowden My app's status is still "Rejected". will I wait more?

Comment: @LukeSnowden it's approved today...

Comment: @RipaSaha So what you did to make them approve? How much time did you wait?

Comment: @LorisFoe they approve my app within 1 week.

Comment: How many times you have submitted your build for approval?
I am suffering from the same issue can you help me to do it in a better way.
What you had found why it was happening.?

Comment: Can you explain how you approved your app after a lot of rejection

Comment: @KumarLav basically, once submitted leave it. If it comes back saying failed but has been referred for someone to look over it, leave it. Don't resubmit as that will cause the whole process to start again and you will lose your original possession in the queue.

Comment: @LukeSnowden My 2 apps rejected recently. I'm, getting the same issue. What should I do?

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani did you got approved your apps ?

Comment: @UmerWaqas You got this message too?

Comment: I have fixed the issue, this is not a perfect solution but as it worked for so i will definitely share it with you, you have to find another Developer Account and upload your app the new Developer account once it approved then transfer your app to your previous app Developer account !!!

Comment: After my app update got rejected "review of your app is taking longer than expected", on the next day the status changed back to "In Review", and 20 hour later it was finally changed to "Pending Developer Release". I didn't upload a new build or sent a message to the Resolution Center. Never experienced such an app review reject before... maybe Apple was out of human capacity for a short time. Don't panic :)